# How to align image when delete button appears in UITableview

Tags: iphone

i have image in UITableView right side of the Tableview Cell

While deleting the cell it showing delete button on for cell but the image is cover on the delete button. [over laps the image]

How do i aligne the image when the delete button appears.

Answer (score 0):

Set appropriate property `autoresizingMask` of your `UIImageView` object.

In your case, if I'm not mistaken, you should set something like this:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

If you are creating your custom cell in IB then you can set this property in `Utilities->Size inspector->Origin` (the picture with `- - - - -` and red lines is clickable)

Comment: imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;


Its working for only row 1 

I called it in delegate method.